# Applying multiple permutations of mocks to dependencies for better unit testing in Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

Let's say I have a class (OrchestratingClass) that has a method `orchestrate()` that calls a number of smaller methods of other classes (classA's `do1()` method, classB's `do2()` method). I would like to test the behavior of `orchestrate()` by mocking the responses of `do1()` and `do2()` with various permutations. I'm running my test with something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public OrchestratingClassTest {

    @Inject 
    private OrchestratingClass oc;

    @Test 
    public void test1() {
        // I would like to mock classA's do1() method to send back "1"
        // I would like to mock classB's do2() method to send back "2"
    }

    @Test 
    public void test2() {
        // I would like to mock classA's do1() method to send back "100"
        // I would like to mock classB's do2() method to send back "200"
    }

    static class SimpleConfig {

        @Bean
        public InterfaceA interfaceA() {
            return new ClassA();
        }

        @Bean
        public InterfaceB interfaceB() {
            return new ClassB();
        }

        @Bean
        public OrchestratingClass orchestratingClass() {
            return new OrchestratingClass();
        }
    }
}
```

And the orchestratingClass itself is quite basic, but I've added some sample code to aid in visualization:

```
@Named
public OrchestratingClass {

    @Inject
    private InterfaceA interfaceA;

    @Inject
    private InterfaceB interfaceB;

    public String orchestrate() {
        return interfaceA.do1() + " " + interfaceB.do2();
    }
}
```

Now I'm aware I could tweak my `SimpleConfig` class to have the mocked out versions of classA and classB, but then I'm locked into 1 particular mock and can't "re-mock" things when I move onto test2(). I'm convinced that playing around with the java config files for 1 single test class would not work if we're trying to inject different "flavors" of beans "per-test". Does anyone have any recommendation on what I can do to make sure I'm really testing this thoroughly without being invasive (ex: adding superfluous "setters" for the specific classes in the orchestratingClass to side-step the bean injection pain)? Essentially, I'm looking to "tamper" the applicationContext on a per-test basis for specific beans of interest (along with the necessary housekeeping that's required) by applying a variety of mocks.

Comment: Just don't use Spring at all. You're a standard ocking framework (Mockito, EasyMock) to create a mock ClassA and ClassB instance doing what you want them to do.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm curious how I can side-step Spring in this case given that the classA and classB are actually private inside the OrchestratingClass. I'd like to think my question isn't a weird corner case, so I assumed that Spring would have some hooks to satisfy such a requirement. From your answer it appears that there isn't any first-class way of achieving this in Spring... is that the right assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example using Mockito:

```
public class OrchestratingClassTest {
    @Mock
    private ClassA mockA;

    @Mock
    private ClassB mockB;

    @InjectMocks
    private OrchestratingClass oc;

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldConcatenate() {
        when(mockA.do1()).thenReturn("1");
        when(mockB.do2()).thenReturn("2");
        assertEquals("1 2", oc.orchestrate());
    }
}
```

The magic happens in the call to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`, which will create mock instances for the fields annotated with `@Mock`, then create a real instance of Orchestrating class and inject its fields, thanks to `@InjectMocks`.

Note that, even without this magic, you could make your class easily testable by just adding a constructor taking ClassA and ClassB as arguments to OrchestratingClass, and annotate that constructor with @Autowired instead of annotating the fields. So, in short, use constructor injection rather than field injection.